# How to handle BinaryInteger and BinaryFloatingPoint in one function?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to make a View like

```
struct CalcNumPadView<T: BinaryFloatingPoint>: View {
    @Binding var value: T

    var length: Int = 0

    .....

}
```

**CalcNumPadView** is like a *Calculator*. `Double` is used internary.
When passing `Double`, `Float` value works fine. But can't pass `Int`.

I write a test function on **Playground**

```
import SwiftUI

func myFunc<T: BinaryFloatingPoint>(_ value: T) -> T {
    let a: Double = 5.2

    // handle value as Double
    let b: Double = Double(value)

    // and process.
    let c = a * b
    // This is just sample. Lot of lines to process to calculate.
    // So, I don't wanna make another
    // func myFunc<T: BinaryInteger>(_ value: T) -> T { ... }

    // return calculated value as T
    return T(c)
}

let double: Double = 1.5
let float: Float = 1.5
let cgfloat: CGFloat = 1.5
let int: Int = 10


let resultDouble = myFunc(double)
let resultFloat = myFunc(float)
let resultCGFloat = myFunc(cgfloat)
let resultInt = myFunc(int) // ERROR: Global function 'myFunc' requires that 'Int' conform to 'BinaryFloatingPoint'
```

Error at the last line using `Int`.

> Global function 'myFunc' requires that 'Int' conform to 'BinaryFloatingPoint'

How can I make it?

Comment: you could try using: `let resultInt = Int(myFunc(Double(int)))`

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

But I want pass the value parameter as `@Binding`. I want to pass the value as `@Binding` as CalcNumPadView. I want convert value to T within myFunc().

Comment: How about a protocol which has 2 extensions that conform to `BinaryFloatingPoint` and `BinaryInteger`? You can then extend your required data types like `Float` and `Int` to conform to the protocol and your generic type can be set to that protocol?